# (ReactJs) How do I read user data from firebase authentication users?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to display the current (logged in) users email, that has been saved in  firebase authentication. How do I retrieve it? I want to save it under the variable this.state.email. Here is my code so far:

```
import React from 'react'
import fire from './firebase'


class Home extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.logout = this.logout.bind(this)
        this.state = {
            email: ''
        }
     }
    logout(){
        fire.auth().signOut();
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>You are home</h1>
                <button onClick = {this.logout}>Sign Out</button>
                <p>{this.state.email}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Home
```

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the logged in users email inside your authStateChanged listener . like this.

```
import firebase from "YOUR_FIREBASE_CONFIG_PATH"; 


componentDidMount = () => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (user) {
            console.log(user.email).  // this will print the email if user have any
            this.setState({
                email: user.email,
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you :) Another question, if you don't mind. Once I have this email, how do I export it to another page? export this.state.email isn't working

Comment: you can pass the data to its child component by props . if your  targetcomponent isn't directly a children of your current component then you can use some state management library like redux

Answer (score 0):

Make an API call inside **`componentDidMount`** and save current user detail-email

```
componentDidMount() {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    const { email } = user;
    this.setState({email});
    } 
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Another question, if you don't mind. Once I have this email, how do I export it to another page? export this.state.email isn't working

Comment: @AdvaitDhingra you can pass to child components or save somewhere in common files to use across your project.